# How do I translate the datepicker?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-translate, angular4-forms

I am using angular2-datepicker.I am trying to translate the year and days which shown in the popup.Can anyone help me to sort this out?

[image]

.html

```
<div>
  <my-date-picker name="startdate" [options]="startDateOptions" placeholder=" 
  {{'SELECT_START_DATE'|translate}}" (dateChanged)="onStartDateChanged($event)" required></my-date-picker>
</div>
```

.ts

```
public startDateOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    editableDateField: false,
    openSelectorOnInputClick: true,
    firstDayOfWeek: 'su',
    satHighlight: true,
    selectionTxtFontSize: '13px',
    height: '26px',
    disableSince: this.getCurrentDate()
};
public endDateOptions: IMyDpOptions = this.startDateOptions;
```

Comment: translate the year and dates? what do you mean ?

Comment: The above image shows the date picker.I want to translate the month (for eg nov into other language), day and the text today.

Comment: Did you use `monthLabels` ?

Comment: No.By default the monthlabel is shown

Comment: Yeah, you can override it with translated values. Is not it?

Comment: No..I couldn't.

Comment: ex: monthLabels: { 1: 'First month', 2: 'second month', ... , 12: 'Last month' }

Comment: what is your problem... i create example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgzbfj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I want to translate the days and month to different languages

Comment: Can you give an example? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wm1brk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I solved the issue by override it with translated values

Comment: Updated the link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n5x5e9